# Laravel Blade variables in view

Tags: php, laravel, templates, laravel-blade

I am working on the front end of a Laravel project and I can change all the values in the view templates. I can probably modify other files as well, but, as I don't yet grok Laravel Blade fully, and I have a time constraint, I'd prefer not to make life harder for myself.

What I want to do is output some data related to the current route, and retrieve and parse some data from the Resources/lang/values.php file.  Can I do this within the view without inserting a bunch of messy php?  Is this a stupid thing to do?  Is their a best practice for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `__()` or `trans()` helpers or `@lang` Blade directive to work with language files:

```
{{ __('values.some_string_from_values_language_files') }}
```

Or:

```
@lang('values.some_string_from_values_language_files')
```

These helpers will work only if `values.php` is in:

```
resources/lang/en/values.php
resources/lang/fr/values.php
....
```

An answer to your question about best practices is no, you shouldn't reinvent the wheel and keep language files in a standard directory.

To get current route data, use `Route` facade and these methods:

```
$route = Route::current();
$name = Route::currentRouteName();
$action = Route::currentRouteAction();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#accessing-the-current-route

Comment: That is very helpful.  The "some_string" will have data from the route.  I assume I can use a variable for "some_string"?  You don't have to answer this.  I will look at the link and ask in a comment if I am unclear.  Thank you very much!